# How to count total crossover from two tables each with specific conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working from two tables in a dataset. Let's call the first one 'Demographic_Info', the other 'Study_Info'. The two tables both have a Subject_ID column. How can I run a query that will return all of the Subject_IDs where Sex = Male (from Demographic_Info) but also where the Study Case = Case (from Study_Info)?

Is this an inner join? Do I need to make a combined table?

I just don't know what function to use. I know how to select for each of these conditions in each table individually, but not how to run them against eachother.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will want to inner join and then use the where clause to filter on both tables.

```
select
  s.Subject_ID
from `Study_info` s
inner join `Demographic_info` d on s.Subject_ID = d.Subject_ID
where d.Sex = 'Male'
  and s.Study_Case = 'Case' -- Unclear from your question about the actual field name
```

The aliases `s` and `d` will be useful for organizing which table each field comes from (or if the same field occurs in both tables).

Similarly, you could filter first and then perform the join.

```
with study as (select * from `Study_info` where Study_Case = 'Case'),
     demographics as (select * from `Demographic_info` where Sex = 'Male')
select s.Subject_ID
from study s
inner join demographics d on s.Subject_ID = d.Subject_ID
```